# codeigniter inside multiple checkbox

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have small problem with my PHP code. I must insert to database multiple values but I dont have any idea how I can do this.

### My View:

```
<?php foreach($myKidsGroupID as $row): ?>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="user_my_group_msg" value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>" class="my_group_msg pull-right"><?php echo $row->firstname; ?> <?php echo $row->lastname; ?></label><br>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

### And my Model looks like this:

```
...

elseif($checked_my_group == 1) {

                    foreach ( ?? ) {
                    $new_mail = array(
                    'to_user'           =>  $this->input->post('user_my_group_msg'),
                    );

                    $this->db->insert('mailbox', $new_mail);
                }

            }
...rest code....
```

Inside my View I display all users as checkbox but If I select two persons I must INSERT two query to database. Anyone can help me?

Comment: this name name="user_my_group_msg" should be `name="user_my_group_msg[]"`

Comment: Yes but what I must use in foreach() ? I dont have idea ://

Comment: name="user_my_group_msg" should be `name="user_my_group_msg[]"` and `foreach` `$this->input->post['user_my_group_msg']`

Answer (score 2):

simple thing is 
use `serialize` function don't use foreach

```
serialize $this->input->post('user_my_group_msg')
```

Comment: Doesnt work :( If I insert to database using this method I get one row in database but inside column "to_user" i have strange datas :( 

I must INSERT one ROW as ONE checkbox :(

E.x.

Checkbox1 - checked
Checkbox2 - checked
Checkbox3 - no checked

But in database should be as:

row1: ------ datas from checkbox1
row2: ------ datas from checkbox2
row3: Didn't create becouse I dont click "check" ...

Sorry for my bad English :(

Comment: then you need to change checkbox name.Each checkbox have different name and it would be easy to save and update

Answer (score 0):

**try it once it will help you your View code will look as like**

```
<?php foreach($myKidsGroupID as $row): ?>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="user_my_group_msg" value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>" class="my_group_msg pull-right"><?php echo $row->firstname; ?> <?php echo $row->lastname; ?></label><br>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

**Model will be corrected like this**

```
<?php  
elseif(sizeof($this->input->post('user_my_group_msg'))>=1) {

    foreach ( $this->input->post('user_my_group_msg') as $value ) {
        $new_mail = array(
        'to_user'           =>  $value,
        );
        $this->db->insert('mailbox', $new_mail);
    }

}
.....rest code
        ?>
```